# Regex to find old library ref codes in ebook file names

Tags: regex

Looking for a regex to find and remove old library reference codes from ebook file names.
The codes are in the format:

Open square bracket, one to three capital letters, a hyphen, one to four numbers, close square bracket (OR, a comma, second code of the same format, then the close square bracket).

Some examples:

`[MHS-679]`
`[MB-376]`
`[R-1167]`
`[HRS-1288]`
`[HCC-29]`
`[SD-1077, MD-1096]`
`[HP-2225, R-76]`

I'm using File Renamer. I'm new to regex so haven't tried anything on this yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression, this will match either a single or double code reference.

```
\[[A-Z]{1,3}-[0-9]{1,4}(, *[A-Z]{1,3}-[0-9]{1,4})?]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/\[(([A-Z]{1,3}\-[0-9]{1,4}),\s*)*([A-Z]{1,3}\-[0-9]{1,4})\]/g
```

[Testing page here](http://www.regexr.com/39f7j).

I made it sufficiently generic by the way that it also recognizes 3 or more codes in a single reference. If that is definitely not intended, replace the`)*(` in the middle with `)?(`.

Answer (score 0):

This regex matches your target:

```
(?<=\[)[A-Z]{1,3}-\d{1,4}(?:, *[A-Z]{1,3}-\d{1,4})?(?=\])
```

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/Zsw7KWrnQi)

This regex uses look arounds to assert, but not capture, the square brackets, so the *entire* match is your target (ie group 0).